# Music in .jar and BasicPlayer 3.0

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Im working with Netbeans. Im using BasicPlayer 3.0 libs, to play a song, it plays fine when a run project with Netbeans BUT once a have my .jar file (with my lib folder and basicplayer3.0 jars) when a run my .jar project, mp3 song NEVER plays.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, your application is not finding the mp3 file/resource from within the jar. If your mp3 file is held *inside* of the jar file, then you cannot access it as a file, but rather as a *resource*, and the path to the resource is different from that of a file. For a resource, the path will be relative to your class files.

For more help, show us the code where you obtain and try to use your mp3 file.

Comment: I think you have reason! My part of the code: 
`reproductor=new BasicPlayer();
        try{
            musica=new File(getClass().getResource("/bibliotecamultimedia/music/cancion.mp3").toURI());
            reproductor.open(musica);
            reproductor.play();
        }catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println(error);
        }`

Comment: @user2350872: you'll want to show your code as an edit or better an addendum to your original question since comments cannot format code. But yeah, you're using `new File(...)` something you shouldn't be doing if the mp3 is held inside of the jar.